# Query XPath in Adobe CRX

Tags: xpath, crx

I am performing an XPath query in Adobe CRX and I am trying to find a list of nodes that contains the string 'Xbox Live'. What I am getting back are nodes that contain both 'Xbox' and 'Live'. I am wondering what would the query be to get an exact match of my string.

Current XPath Query: `/jcr:root/content//*[jcr:contains(., 'Xbox Live')] order by @jcr:score`

Example of content that I want returned:

- This offer requires an Xbox Live account
- Your Xbox Live user name is not valid
- XBox Live is the future!

Example of content that I do not want returned:

- Xbox and Playstation will live forever
- Will I live longer then my Xbox?
- The Xbox out lived my Wii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath/xquery is fine, that should return elements containing exact phrase `"Xbox Live"`, assuming Adobe CRX has decent xpath 1.0 implementation.

Possible catch is, by using `.` in `contains()` concatenation of all descendant text nodes will be evaluated. For example, the following `parent` element also considered matched the `contains(., 'Xbox Live')` predicate :

```
<parent>Xbox <child>Live</child></parent>
```

If you want to evaluate `contains()` to individual text nodes, and return parent element of matched text nodes, try the following instead :

```
/jcr:root/content//text()[jcr:contains(., 'Xbox Live')]/parent::* order by @jcr:score
```